# I can not get "exit status" with "timeout comand"

Tags: bash, unix, timeout

I expect to get "status 124", but got "status 0" with the following code

```
timeout 10 sleep 20 | tee -a LOG_FILE LOG_FILE2
RET=$?
echo $RET
```

I got "status 0" by use this code.

I expect to get "status 124".

What's happen in this code

Comment: script should return `124 or 137`, if you able to see `Killed` message on terminal or `stderr` ??

Comment: The $? is the status of the last command. i.e. in your case the tee.

Comment: `$?` will provide you the return value of `timeout`, I run your script and got 137

Comment: here `tee -a` doesn't append anything to `LOG_FILE LOG_FILE2` because no output from timeout command.. only you get error message `Killed`

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed code.

Comment: i got "status 0" by shellscrit, but I got "status 124" by termminal. Why did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$?` holds the exit status of the last pipeline. Use `PIPESTATUS` to get the exit status of foreground pipelines (in this case the `timeout` command).

```
$ timeout 10 sleep 20 | tee -a LOG_FILE LOG_FILE2
$ RET=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
$ echo $RET

124  # timed out
```

**man bash**

> **PIPESTATUS**: An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Comment: @Sh.nakayama: See `echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` and `declare -p PIPESTATUS`, too.

Comment: @Travis Clarke thank you very much. you are correct.